# CloudKit Subscription Notifications not sending

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, notifications, cloudkit

So, I'm using CloudKit to store Posts for a social media app I'm building. A post has a username called a 'Plate', and I would like users to be able to get notified when a Post is created with a specified Plate. I'm using CloudKit Query Subscriptions to do this, but I'm getting some problems.

The user can press a button to create the subscription, and I can see (in the CloudKit dashboard) that the subscription has been created successfully. But when I create a record, the push notification is never sent.

Weirdly, the notifications used to work but stopped seemingly randomly.

Some debugging I've already done:

- I am using a different iCloud account to create the record than to get the notification
- The subscription is created on a physical device (not a simulator)
- I have tried setting the Predicate to a TRUEPREDICATE to eliminate issues with that
- I have requested (and been granted) permission to send push notifications
- I have registered for remote notifications (and it has done this successfully)
- My Notification Info has values (at least one of its values is not null)
- I tried changing the options to .firesOnRecordUpdate (and this worked briefly but stopped for some reason, currently only .firesOnRecordDelete works)

When I get a notification for .firesOnRecordDelete, the notification pops up very briefly and disappears (and the badge number is on something like 28 but then immediately disappears as well)

UPDATE: .firesOnRecordDeletion no longer works either

Here is the code I use to create the subscription:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
    if error == nil {
        let container = CKContainer.init(identifier: "MY CONTAINER ID")
        let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase

        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
                    
        let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Post", predicate: predicate, options: [.firesOnRecordCreation])
                    
        let notificationInfo = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
                                                            
        notificationInfo.title = "New post for " + self.selectedPlate! // selectedPlate is just a string
        notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
        notificationInfo.soundName = "default"
        notificationInfo.desiredKeys = ["Plate"]
        notificationInfo.alertBody = "Someone posted something against a number plate you're interested in."
        notificationInfo.shouldBadge = false
                    
        subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
                    
        publicDatabase.save(subscription) { result, error in
            print("subscription save")
            if let error = error {
                print("subscription error" + error.localizedDescription)
                
            } else {
                print("subscription saved")
                print(result)
                
                            
            }
        }
    } else {
        print(error)
    }    
}
```

Heres how I register for Remote Notifications (and I can see it is registered) :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    print("is registered = " + String(describing: application.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications))
}
```

Here is how I handle the remote Notification (I was going to change this when the notifications were working):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.noData)
}
```

Here is my user notifications willPresent function:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.banner, .sound, .badge])
}
```

I've been trying to fix this for weeks, I appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: I've done some testing on my end, and this looks like an outage on Apple's end. I am not getting any background notifications from records changes this week, but it was working last week. I'll file a FB with Apple.

Comment: Just submitted `FB9525059`. I'll post an update here if I get anything back from Apple.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Thanks, mine broke around last week as well. Annoyingly it stopped woking right when I made a change to my code, so I spent a week thinking it was my fault haha

Comment: I haven't received a response on my `FB` yet, but I have started getting random notifications. They'll come really late and only for certain record types, so maybe they are at least poking around CloudKit to see what's going on.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I started a TSI a few days ago and they have confirmed its an issue at their end, although they made out like it is only an issue with my container specifically. They told me to make a new container since my app is not on the App Store yet.

Comment: It's been a year since this question was posted, and I am having same issue with subscriptions. Has there been any solution to this?